# page size if element is hidden

Tags: html, hidden

If a element is hidden then does it effect the page size while loading.

For example an image is hidden.Now when the page loads for the time will it calculate the size of that image too?

There can be 50 hidden images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you hide it with CSS, still HTML will request those images from the server, if you really want that page loads quick than you need to comment out `img` tags on your page, this won't only hide the images, but it won't request the images from the server too, thus resulting in faster page loading.

You can also use CSS sprites if you've tons of small icons on your websites, if you are talking about literal images than you can check out lazy load technique if you want to render images with faster page loading

Comment: If I comment out img tags then how can I display the images again on click or on mouseover event.

Comment: @Raj If you are calling them on events, than image loads at that time, you should mention all this in your question

Comment: ah sorry for that.Thanks so much for your suggestion.